# how to keep the graphic2D shape to stay for a period time in java?

Tags: java, geometry

I'm going to create a moving circle for my later project, and the circle will keep moving, and it interior color will change like color emitting , the changing color will from little circle to larger circle in 5 levels, so how to keep each color change to stay a while and I hope these code present with thread, so I create two thread for the purpose, one control circle moving, another control the circle's interior color emit
here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Color.black;
import static java.awt.Color.yellow;
import static java.awt.FlowLayout.RIGHT;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
class thepane extends JPanel implements Runnable{
   public float x,y,r;
   public float speedx,speedy;
    thepane(float lx,float ly,float lr, float sx,float sy){
        loadspeed(sx,sy);
        load(lx,ly,lr);
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            fc[i]=new Color(nd.nextInt(255),nd.nextInt(255),nd.nextInt(255)); 
    }

    public void load(float lx,float ly,float lr){   
        x=lx;y=ly;r=lr;
    }
    public void loadspeed(float sx,float sy){
        speedx=sx;speedy=sy;
    }
    public void xmoving(){
        x+=speedx;
    }
    public void ymoving(){
        y-=speedy;
    }
    public void touchbond(){
        if(x>getWidth()-r||x<0)
         speedx*=-1;   
        if(y>getHeight()-r||y<0)
        speedy*=-1;          
        if(x>getWidth()-r)
            x=getWidth()-r;
        else if(x<0)
            x=0;
        if(y>getHeight()-r)
            y=getHeight()-r;
        else if(y<0)
            y=0;
    }         
    Random nd=new Random();   
    int colorcount=0;
    int emitcount=0;
    boolean emit=false;
    Color[] fc=new Color[5]; 
    Graphics2D  comp2D ;     
    Thread athread;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {        
        comp2D = (Graphics2D) comp;
        //create rectangle background
        comp2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        comp2D.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        //set information text
        comp2D.setFont( new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        comp2D.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        comp2D.drawString("Centre("+(x+r/2)+' '+(y+r/2)+"), xspeed: "+speedx+" yspeed: "+speedy, 10f,10f );
        comp2D.drawString("panel width "+getWidth()+" panel height "+getHeight()+" circle radius "
                +r, 10f, 22f);
    }
    //thread run()
    @Override
    public void run() {     
        x=100;y=100;
        System.out.println("thread in pane start!!!! (current colorcount = "+colorcount+')');       
        while(true){  
        circleEmit(fc[colorcount%5]);
        repaint();
       sleeping(1);
       // comp2D=(Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
      //  colorEmit(comp2D);
         }
       }
    //wait method
   public void waiting(){
    try{wait();}
    catch(Exception e){}}
    public void waiting2D(int time){
    try{comp2D.wait(time);}
    catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public void waiting(int time){
    try{wait(time);}
    catch(Exception e){}
    }    
    //sleep method
    public void sleeping(int n){
      try{
          Thread.sleep(n);
          }catch(Exception f){
          System.out.print(f);
          }    
    }  
    Ellipse2D.Float[] e=new Ellipse2D.Float[5];
    public void loade(){
        float centrex=x+r/2,centrey=y+r/2;
        e[0]= new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-r/10, centrey-r/10, r/5, r/5);
        e[1]= new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-r/5, centrey-r/5, 2*r/5, 2*r/5);
        e[2]= new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-3*r/10, centrey-3*r/10, 3*r/5, 3*r/5);
        e[3]= new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-2*r/5, centrey-2*r/5, 4*r/5, 4*r/5);
        e[4]= new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-r/2, centrey-r/2, r, r); 
    }   
    public Color ff;
    public synchronized void circleEmit(Color fc){
        comp2D=(Graphics2D)this.getGraphics();
        loade();
        comp2D.setColor(fc);
        comp2D.fill(e[emitcount%5]);
        waiting(5);
        emitcount++;
    }          
    public synchronized void callnotify(){
        this.notify();       
    }
       //iterative way to generate color emit        
    public  void colorEmit(Graphics2D comp2D){
         //create circle
        //set circle property    
        float centrex=x+r/2,centrey=y+r/2;//so x=centrex-r/2;y=centrey+r/2  
        Ellipse2D.Float e1 = new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-r/10, centrey-r/10, r/5, r/5);
        Ellipse2D.Float e2 = new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-r/5, centrey-r/5, 2*r/5, 2*r/5);
        Ellipse2D.Float e3 = new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-3*r/10, centrey-3*r/10, 3*r/5, 3*r/5);
        Ellipse2D.Float e4 = new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-2*r/5, centrey-2*r/5, 4*r/5, 4*r/5);
        Ellipse2D.Float e5 = new Ellipse2D.Float(centrex-r/2, centrey-r/2, r, r);  
            if(colorcount>=4)
                emit(comp2D,fc[(colorcount-4)%5],e5);
            waiting(1000);
            if(colorcount>=3)
                emit(comp2D,fc[(colorcount-3)%5],e4);   
            waiting(1000);
            if(colorcount>=2)
                emit(comp2D,fc[(colorcount-2)%5],e3);    
            waiting(1000);
            if(colorcount>=1)
                emit(comp2D,fc[(colorcount-1)%5],e2);    
            waiting(1000);
            emit(comp2D,fc[colorcount%5],e1);            
            waiting(1000);
            colorcount++;        
    }
    private void emit(Graphics2D comp,Color thecolor,Ellipse2D.Float f){
            comp.setColor(thecolor);
            comp.fill(f);    
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//main class
public class drawpanel extends Thread implements ActionListener{
       JFrame frame=new JFrame();
       thepane panel;    
       JButton FlyingBalls=new JButton("balls"),exit=new JButton("Exit"),stop=new JButton("Stop");
       JButton slow=new JButton("slow down"),resume=new JButton("resume");
       Float x,y,r;

    public void sleeping(int n){
      try{
          Thread.sleep(n);
          }catch(Exception f){
          System.out.print(f);
          }    
    }   
    Thread newthread,pthread;
    Thread[] five=new Thread[5];
    drawpanel(){
       frame.setTitle("FlyingBalls");
       frame.setLocation(100, 100);
       frame.setLayout(null);
       //x,y,r,speedx,speedy
       panel=new thepane(nd.nextInt(800),nd.nextInt(500),40,nd.nextFloat()*20+1,nd.nextFloat()*10+1);
       panel.setSize(800,500);
       frame.setSize(810,580);
       frame.add(panel);      
       FlyingBalls.setSize(80,30);exit.setSize(70,30);stop.setSize(70,30);slow.setSize(140,30);
       resume.setSize(100,30);
       FlyingBalls.addActionListener(this);
       exit.addActionListener(this);
       stop.addActionListener(this);slow.addActionListener(this);resume.addActionListener(this);
       frame.add(FlyingBalls);frame.add(exit); frame.add(stop);frame.add(slow);frame.add(resume);
       FlyingBalls.setLocation(20,500);exit.setLocation(190, 500);stop.setLocation(110,500);
       slow.setLocation(270,500);resume.setLocation(420,500);
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       
       //control moving ball
       newthread=new Thread(this);
       //control color change
       for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
       five[i]=new Thread(panel);
       }
      // newthread.start();
           panel.colorcount++;
           five[0].start();
           panel.colorcount=2;
          // five[1].start();
           panel.waiting(5);
    }
    
   public static void main(String[] arg){
       drawpanel apanel=new drawpanel();     
    }
   int bw=800,bh=500;
   void setp(){
       x=panel.x;y=panel.y;
   }
   void touchbond(){
       System.out.println("width:"+panel.getWidth()+"Height:"+panel.getHeight());
       System.out.println("xposition:"+x+"yposition:"+y);
   if(x+r>panel.getWidth()){
       panel.speedx*=-1;
       x=bw-r;
   }
   else if(x-r<0){
       panel.speedx*=-1;
       x=r;
   }
   if(y-r<0){
       panel.speedy*=-1;
       y=r;
   }
   else if(y+r>panel.getHeight()){
       panel.speedy*=-1;
       y=bh-r;
   }
   panel.x=x;panel.y=y;
   }
   int T=10;
   Random nd=new Random();
       @Override
   public void run(){     
       r=panel.r;      
       panel.loadspeed(-6.33f,-3.4f);
       while(true){      
       if(stopcount==0){//button control variable
       panel.xmoving();panel.ymoving(); 
       panel.touchbond();
       sleeping(T);}
       panel.loade();
   //    panel.callnotify();
      // panel.colorEmit(panel.comp2D);
       panel.repaint();
       }
   }
       @Override
   public void start(){
       
   }
   int count=0,stopcount=0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==exit){
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(e.getSource()==FlyingBalls){
 
            //panel=new thepane();
        }
        if(e.getSource()==resume){
            stopcount=0;T=10;
            panel.emit=false;
        }
        if(e.getSource()==slow){
            if(count%2==0)
            T=500;
            else
                T=10;
            count++;
        }
        if(e.getSource()==stop){
        stopcount++;
        panel.emit=true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sooo, let's start with Swing is NOT thread safe, so any update to the UI or something UI relies on, should be done from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  What you need to do is make some determinations about what should happen at certain points in time.  So if the time from the animation starting to the animation ending is 10 seconds, every 2 seconds, something needs to change (5 key events)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please clarify what are you asking for?

Comment: it's a moving circle in a JPanel, and the circle's color is not simple solid, its color will continous change from inner smaller circle to the whole circle in 5 level, so there can be 5 different color present in the circle simultaneously, I hope solve this in animation in java thread, on thread control the motion of the circle, and another thread control the color change inside the circle, do you have any ideas,

Answer (score 0):

So, lots of theory to cover.

## Firstly...

Animation is not easy, good animation is hard.

## Swing is single threaded and is not thread safe

This means that you should not perform any long running or blocking operations within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

It also means that you shouldn't modify the UI or anything the UI relies on from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

## More threads != more work

More threads doesn't always mean you're going to get more done.  In fact, in this scenario, it could really cause a huge number of issues, as you need the ability to reason out the state at a single point in time (when painting)

## Animation Theory

Okay, animation is simply the illusion of change, how you accomplish that will come down to the problem you trying to solve.

For me, the best animations are time based animations, not linear.

A linear animation keeps updating from its start state till it reaches its end state, in a constant progression.  These don't tend to scale well and can suffer issues on low performant systems.

A time based animation is one where the amount of time is defined and then, based on a anchor time (ie start time) and the state of the animation is updated based on the amount of time which is passed.  This is a really simple way to achieve "frame dropping".  You'd also be very surprised to find that in general terms, time based animations tend to look better across more platforms.

A time based animation is also more capable of generating "easement" effects, but that's getting way deeper then we need to go right now.

Okay, but what's this got to do with your problem?  Well, actually, quite a bit.

The first thing we need is some kind of "main-loop" from which all the animation can be driven.  Typically, I'd look to a good animation library, but failing that, a simple Swing `Timer` will do the basic good really well.

It generates its ticks in the Event Dispatching Thread, which makes it very useful for our needs.  See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

So, we start with something like...

```
private Timer timer;

//...

timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Update the state
        repaint();
    }
});

//...

timer.start();
```

This gives us our "main loop", from which we can update the state as needed and then trigger a repaint of the component.

For the purpose of this demonstration, I'm going to devise a self-contained unit of "animation duration", used to track the amount of time which has passed since the animation was started, this is personal choice, but it would allow me to drive a number of animations and it contains the logic to a single unit of work.

```
public class AnimationDuration {
    private Duration duration;
    private Instant startedAt;

    public AnimationDuration(Duration duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }
    
    public void start() {
        startedAt = Instant.now();
    }

    public void stop() {
        startedAt = null;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return startedAt != null;
    }
    
    public float getProgress() {
        Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startedAt, Instant.now());
        if (runningTime.compareTo(duration) > 0) {
            runningTime = duration;
        }
        long total = duration.toMillis();
        float progress = runningTime.toMillis() / (float) total;
        
        return progress;
    }
    
}
```

This basically allows to trigger the animation to start running (anchor point in time) and then get the progress of the animation at any point in time.  This provides a normalised concept from 0-1, so if we want to make it longer or shorter, all we do is adjust the duration and everything else is taken care of.

For your specific problem, I'd consider some kind of "time line" or "key frames", which defines that certain actions should occur at certain points of time along the time line.

Now, the following is a really simple concept, but it gets the job.

```
public interface KeyFrame {
    public float getProgress();
}

public class TimeLine<K extends KeyFrame> {

    private List<K> keyFrames;

    public TimeLine() {
        keyFrames = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    // Returns the key frames between the current progression
    public K getKeyFrameAt(float progress) {
        for (int index = 0; index < keyFrames.size(); index++) {
            K keyFrame = keyFrames.get(index);
            if (progress >= keyFrame.getProgress()) {
                if (index + 1 < keyFrames.size()) {
                    K nextFrame = keyFrames.get(index + 1);
                    // But only if your between each other
                    if (progress < nextFrame.getProgress()) {
                        return keyFrame;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Nothing after me :D
                    return keyFrame;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void add(K keyFrame) {
        keyFrames.add(keyFrame);
        Collections.sort(keyFrames, new Comparator<KeyFrame>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(KeyFrame lhs, KeyFrame rhs) {
                if (lhs.getProgress() > rhs.getProgress()) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (lhs.getProgress() < rhs.getProgress()) {
                    return -1;
                }

                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This allows you to define certain `KeyFrame`s along the timeline, based on a normalised concept of time and then provides the ability to get the `KeyFrame` based on the current progression through animation.

There are much more complex solutions you might consider, which would generate self contained events based on time progressions automatically, but I prefer been able to driver the animation itself independently, makes these types of things more flexible - add a `JSlider` and you can manipulate the progression manually ;)

The next thing we need is something to carry the properties for the circle `KeyFrame` ...

```
public class CirclePropertiesKeyFrame implements KeyFrame {

    private float progress;

    private double radius;
    private Color color;

    public CirclePropertiesKeyFrame(float progress, double radius, Color color) {
        this.progress = progress;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "KeyFrame progress = " + getProgress() + "; raidus= " + radius + "; color = " + color;
    }

}
```

Now, we need to put it together...

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private AnimationDuration timelineDuration;
    private TimeLine<CirclePropertiesKeyFrame> timeLine;
    private Timer timer;

    private CirclePropertiesKeyFrame circleProperties;

    public TestPane() {
        timelineDuration = new AnimationDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        timeLine = new TimeLine<>();
        timeLine.add(new CirclePropertiesKeyFrame(0, 5, Color.CYAN));
        timeLine.add(new CirclePropertiesKeyFrame(0.2f, 10, Color.BLUE));
        timeLine.add(new CirclePropertiesKeyFrame(0.4f, 15, Color.GREEN));
        timeLine.add(new CirclePropertiesKeyFrame(0.6f, 20, Color.YELLOW));
        timeLine.add(new CirclePropertiesKeyFrame(0.8f, 25, Color.MAGENTA));
        timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (timelineDuration.isRunning()) {
                    float progress = timelineDuration.getProgress();
                    if (progress >= 1.0) {
                        timelineDuration.stop();
                    }
                    CirclePropertiesKeyFrame keyFrame = timeLine.getKeyFrameAt(progress);
                    circleProperties = keyFrame;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        timelineDuration.start();
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeNotify() {
        super.removeNotify();
        timer.stop();
        timelineDuration.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (circleProperties != null) {
            double radius = circleProperties.radius;
            double xPos = (getWidth() / 2) - radius;
            double yPos = (getHeight() / 2) - radius;

            g2d.setColor(circleProperties.color);
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos, yPos, radius * 2, radius * 2));
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

And then we end up with something like...

[image: Simple animation]

Now, this is a 10 second sequence, so every 2 seconds it will update.  Try changing the duration of the `AnimationDuration` and see what happens.

*Note* This is a non-repeating animation (it doesn't loop).  You could make it loop, but the calculation to do so becomes more complicate, as you need to consider by how much you're over the expected `Duration` and then apply that to the next cycle, so it looks smooth

> But what about movement?

Well, actually, pretty much already answered that question.  You would also place the movement code inside the `Timer`s `ActionListener`, right before the `repaint` request.  In fact, I might be tempted to create some kind of class that could take the current `KeyFrame` information and combine it with the location properties, this would then be used the `paintComponent` method to draw the circle.

> I want to blend the animation states ...

Well, that's a much more difficult question, especially when it comes to colors.

The basic theory is, you need the two key frames which set either side of the current progression.  You would then apply a "blending" algorithm to calculate the amount of change to be applied between the two key frames.

Not impossible, just a step more difficult